# Question about limit of a product

Tags: calculus, limits

> Is it possible that both $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ do not exist but $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ does exist?

The reason I ask is that I was able to show that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist but both $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ do exist, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$. However, I'm not sure whether the assumption on the existence of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x) = g(x)$ be a function that is $1$ on the rationals and $-1$ on the irrationals.

Comment: This is a very neat example.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=7+\sin(1/x)$, $g(x)=1/f(x)$, $a=0$.

Comment: I tried constructing a counterexample using $f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ but $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ isn't defined on an open neighbourhood of $0$. By adding $7$, you get $f(x) \in [6, 8]$ so the corresponding $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As a simple example, I'll work with sequences.  Let $f(n) = (-1)^n$ and $g(n) = (-1)^{n}$.  Then $f(n)g(n) = 1$, so $1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)g(n)$, but neither of the individual limits exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two disjoint sequences $u_n\to a$ and $v_n\to a$

i.e. $\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cap\{b_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\varnothing$

You can define $\begin{cases}f(a_n)=1 & \forall n\in\mathbb N\\f(x)=0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\quad$ and $\quad\begin{cases}g(b_n)=1 & \forall n\in\mathbb N\\g(x)=0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

It is clear that $f(x)g(x)=0$ everywhere so it has a limit zero, while neither $f$ nor $g$ has a limit. And you can smoothen these functions if desired to get a $C^\infty$ example, just make sure that $f$ and $g$ bumps do not coincide.